# discovering the biggest value in a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, max, key-value-store

I'm trying to figure out the biggest value within a dictionary, and I'm having some trouble with this.
Here's my code:

```
def most_fans(dictionary):
    empty = ''
    for key in dictionary:
        if len(dictionary[key]) > next(dictionary[key]):
            empty = key
    print(empty)
```

I realize the problem with my code, since if I have a dictionary such as this:

```
fans={'benfica': ['joao','ana','carla'],
      'sporting': ['hugo','patricia'],
      'porto': ['jose']}
```

The output will be both `'benfica'` and `'sporting'`.Because benfica is bigger then sporting but sporting is also bigger then porto. And yet this the best I  came up with.

Can someone show me a decent way to do this?

Comment: Have you tried `max()`?

Comment: By "biggest value" do you mean "longest string value" or "longest list" or something else? And in your example data, shouldn't the result be 'benfica' since its list has length 3?

Comment: I have and it still game me the same result, i didn't get why so I tried something different...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could just use `max()` with a key:

```
>>> max(fans, key=lambda team:len(fans[team]))
'benfica'
```

Here:

- `max(fans, ...)` iterates over the keys of `fans` (that is, team names) looking for the largest element according to some criterion;
- the lambda function specifies that criterion (in this example, the number of fans the team has).

Answer (score 2):

If you have two teams with same number of fans:

```
fans = {'benfica':['joao','ana','carla'],
        'sporting':['hugo','patricia', 'max'],
        'porto':['jose']}
```

The `max()`approach gives you only one of them:

```
>>> max(fans, key=lambda team:len(fans[team]))
'benfica'
```

Using [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter), you can get the most common ones:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> counts = Counter({k: len(v) for k, v in fans.items()})
>>> counts.most_common(2)
[('benfica', 3), ('sporting', 3)]
```

or all:

```
>>> counts.most_common()
[('benfica', 3), ('sporting', 3), ('porto', 1)]
```

Comment: i believe `counts.most_common(len(counts)) == counts.most_common()`

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> max_val = lambda xs: max(xs.iteritems(), key=lambda x: len(x[1]))
>>> max_val(fans)
('benfica', ['joao', 'ana', 'carla'])
```